# How to make a Context API inside an Axios Call

Tags: reactjs, axios

I have a react frontend and an express backend with mongodb. I have managed to encrypt a JWT token, and now I want to pass that same token into my context state , so I can use it in other components to access private routes. For some reason, when I try to setstate on the context api , it doesn't update at all unless I use it directly with a click event. However I would like to update the context state, when I get a response from an Axios call. 
// Context

```
const AuthProvider = props => {
  const [token, setToken] = useState({
    token: ""
  });
  const addToken = UserToken => {
    setToken({ token: UserToken });
  };

  return (
    <AuthContext.Provider value={{ token, addToken, setToken }}>
      {props.children}
    </AuthContext.Provider>
  );
};
```

// The axios call is inside a function called this.UserSubscription

```
  let self = this;

    axios
      .post(`http://localhost:5000/user/${page}`, {
        username,
        password
      })
      .then(function(res) {
        userdata = res;
        if (page === "login") {
          self.setState({
            isUser: true,
            data: res
          });
          self.context.addToken(this.state.data);
        }
        console.log("hi world");
      })
      .catch(function(error) {
        if (error.response) {

          self.setState({
            isError: true,
            error: error.response.data.msg
          });
        }
      });
```

```
<form onSubmit={this.UserSubscription} className="login-form">
                <label>Username</label>
                <input type="text" id="username" name="username" />
                <label className="label-password">Password</label>
                <input type="text" id="password" name="password" />
                <p className="error-msg">{msg}</p>
                <button
                  type="submit"
                  className="form-btn login-btn"
                >
                  {this.props.title}
                </button>
              </form>
```

Comment: Dont see anything wrong with the code. can you 'console.log(JSON.stringify(token))' in AuthProvider just before you return jsx?

Comment: Apparently the problem is the axios call. Without the axios call, it works fine.

Answer (score 2):

There must be something wrong with code you didn't post because I can reproduce the code you posted and it's working fine.

Note that token is in `context.token.token`

```js
const AuthContext = React.createContext();
const AuthProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [token, setToken] = React.useState({
    token: '',
  });
  const addToken = token => setToken({ token });
  return (
    <AuthContext.Provider
      value={{
        token,
        addToken,
      }}
    >
      {children}
    </AuthContext.Provider>
  );
};
class ComponentOne extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    Promise.resolve().then(() =>
      this.context.addToken('hello world')
    );
  }
  render() {
    return <div>in One: {JSON.stringify(this.context.token)}</div>;
  }
}
ComponentOne.contextType = AuthContext;
const ComponentTwo = () => {
  const { token } = React.useContext(AuthContext);
  return <pre>in two: {JSON.stringify(token)}</pre>;
};
const App = () => (
  <AuthProvider>
    <ComponentOne />
    <ComponentTwo />
  </AuthProvider>
);

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.4/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.4/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: I reproduced your code and it works fine. I think the axios call may be the culprit.